# How to fade svg path in/out one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am doing the following but it is fading in/out the path all at once and not one after the other

```
  var periodClass = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class");
  jQuery("svg path").each(function(i) {
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    if (elem.hasClass(periodClass)) {
        elem.addClass('active').css('transition-delay', i/5000 + 's');
    } else {
        elem.removeClass('active').css('transition-delay', i/5000 + 's');
    }
  });
```

CSS

```
path {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

path.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
```

Also tried this but still, all at once

```
  var periodClass = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class");
  jQuery("svg path").each(function(i) {
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    if (elem.hasClass(periodClass)) {
      elem.addClass('active');
      elem.each(function(index) {
          $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
      });
    } else {
      elem.removeClass('active');
      elem.each(function(index) {
          $(this).delay(400*index).fadeOut(300);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout();`

**here's an example**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function(i){
    var ThisIt = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
      ThisIt.addClass('active');
    } , i * 1000);
    
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background : #eee;
  display: none;
}

.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: @rob.m You're Welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do it:

```
 var pnum = 0;
 var $paths = $("svg path");

 nextFade();

 function nextFade () {
    $paths.eq(pnum).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete. Increase counter Call next fade.
        pnum++;
        if(pnum < $paths.length){
            nextFade();
        } 
     });
 }
```

Comment: that includes lots of thing which i don't have such as path ids

Comment: A better pattern would be `$("svg path").eq(pnum)`